# Certificate error from client side while sending HTTP request from Salesforce

Tags: webservices, rest-service, certificates

I am trying to send an Http request from Salesforce to a third party system. Following is the code for http request.

```
    HTTP httpInstance = new HTTP();
    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(endpointURL);
    request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    request.setHeader('srcKey', 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    //request.setClientCertificateName(certificate);
    //request.setClientCertificateName('StudentScoutCertificateBase64');
    try{
        HTTPResponse newResponse = httpInstance.send(request);
        string responseBody = newResponse.getBody();
        system.debug('REST Response '+ responseBody);

    }catch(exception e){
        system.debug('An unexpected error occured: '+ e.getMessage());
    }
```

On sending the request I get a response back from the server with the following error.

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Certificate is valid on client's server. I did download the certificate with Base64 encoding . I then added the certificate using the following

```
request.setClientCertificateName(certificate);
```

I am then getting the following  error.

```
common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: DER input, Integer tag error
```

Not sure how to proceed with this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. There were two reasons for this error.

1. Certificate was not signed by one of the 100+ Salesforce trusted CA.
2. Intermediate certificates were not installed on the client's server.

Once they fixed these two issues, I was able to successfully ping the server.

Following is the link you can use to check if the endpoint certificate is trusted or not

http://www.digicert.com/help/

Comment: Glad you found the solution and thanks for coming back and adding the answer! You should be able to give yourself the check mark too!

Comment: Would the cert not being signed by a Salesforce trusted CA be a problem in this case? setClientCertificateName() is so Salesforce can pass the certificate as part of a web service call, so a cert signed by a CA set up by yourself should work right? It's up to the receiver whether to trust the cert or not. I've been looking for confirmation this is the case or not, but am struggling.

Comment: @GBreavin Yes, cert not being signed by a Salesforce trusted CA was the issue. However Salesforce also suggested similar thing what you are suggesting. The only thing receiver has to do is to add the new CA signed certificate in there server and that will work. However in my case the 3rd party was not willing to add any new certificates which we were providing but went ahead and got the certificate resigned by one of the Salesforce trusted CAs.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the list of trusted cert providers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates)
[Link for directions to install intermediate certificates](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Specifying_Intermediate_CA_Certificates)

Comment: Could you also explain or summarize that witin your answer?